# Customize Wordpress Admin Menu

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to develop a wordpress plugin that will do the customization of the wordpress admin menu - rename, reorder, change menu icons, etc But I couldn't find a proper way to do it. Can anyone please seggest me how to start for this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by you didnt find a proper way to do it?

Comment: I mean I couldn't find a way to start. Is there any hooks or filters so that I can work on it?